# C# extract string using regular expression

Tags: c#

I have a html string which i'm parsing which looks like below. I need to get the value of @Footer.

```
strHTML = "<html><html>\r\n\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=Content-Type 
           content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1252\">\r\n
           <meta name=Generator content=\"Microsoft Word 14></head></head><body> 
           <p>@Footer=CONFIDENTIAL<p></body></html>"
```

I have tried the below code, how do i get the value?

```
Regex m = new Regex("@Footer", RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (Match VariableMatch in m.Matches(strHTML.ToString()))
{
     Console.WriteLine(VariableMatch);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to capture the value after the `=`. This will work, as long as the value cannot contain any `<` characters:

```
Regex m = new Regex("@Footer=([^<]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (Match VariableMatch in m.Matches(strHTML.ToString()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(VariableMatch.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with regex, but it's not necessary. One simple way to do this would be:

```
var match = strHTML.Split(new string[] { "@Footer=" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last();
match = match.Substring(0, match.IndexOf("<"));
```

This assumes that your html string only has one `@Footer`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will match the string "@Footer". The value of the match will be "@Footer".

Your regex should look like this instead :

```
Regex regex = new Regex("@Footer=[\w]+");
string value = match.Value.Split('=')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a matching group.

```
Regex.Matches(strHTML, @"@Footer=(?<VAL>([^<\n\r]+))").Groups["VAL"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's all your string, we can use string methods to solve it without touching regex stuff:

```
var result = strHTML.Split(new string[]{"@Footer=", "<p>"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]
```